# 2.8's Grease Pencil: Is it possible to scale several frames at the same time?

Tags: grease-pencil

I was wondering if it was possible, in Draw mode, to select several (or all) shapes of the same Grease Pencil object and scale/move/rotate them together. For example here select both the star and the spiral, here displayed all at once because the "Onion skinning" option, and scale them up, which would mean have an simultaneous influence on different keyframes.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: (It might be useful to point out that you are talking about shapes at different frames, here displayed all at once because the "Onion skinning" option is enabled)

Comment: thanks, it's done, I hope it's more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Multiframe editing

Make sure to have both the Dope Sheet and the Viewport visible, then

- in the Viewport, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode
- in the Dope Sheet, box select (<kbd>B</kbd>) the keyframes you want to be affected (they will turn yellow):

  [image]
- in the Viewport, make sure that the button next to "*Multiframe*" ([image]) is selected in the top bar
- Make your edits

As of today, you won't be able to preview the effect on the other keyframes (except the current frame) while editing. But going back into object mode will reveal that the edit has taken place for all of them.